# Algebra on random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

If $X$~$Uniform(0,1)$ then $-2X+1$~$Uniform(-1,1)$

This statement is true. But I'm not sure the way I approach this problem is necessarily correct.

I would start with solving $E[-2X+1]$, which boils down to $-2E[X]+1 = -.5$
EDIT: Error here, $-2E[X]+1 = 0$

Then I would call $Y$~$Uniform(-1,1)$, and find the $E[Y]$, which is $0$.

At least, that's how I would approach the problem. Is this enough work?

Comment: Do you agree with me that $\mathbb E(X)=0.5$ ? What is then $-2 \mathbb E(X)+1$ ?

Comment: Yeah I do, I just realized I made an arithmetic error. Is this still the correct way to approach the problem?

Comment: If it would be a contradiction like in your first (wrong) result then you would be finisched, But equal expected values are not sufficient. In my opinion you need the pdf.

Comment: The best approach is to use CDFs here. Namely, show that the CDF of $-2X+1$, that is, $F_{-2X+1}(x):=\mathbb{P}(-2X+1 \leq x)$ is the CDF of the uniform distribution supported on $[-1,1]$. Use the form of $F_X(x):=\mathbb{P}(X \leq x)$ which you know since $X \sim \mathcal{U}(0,1)$. Check the link for the formulae https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the cdf. Let $Z=-2X+1$. Then

$P(Z<z)=P(-2X+1<z)=P(1-z<2X)=P\left(\frac{1-z}{2}<X \right)$

The cdf of X is

$$F_X(x)=\begin{cases}0, \text{if} \ x<0 \\ x, \text{if} \ 0 \leq x<1  \\ 1, \text{if} \ x\geq 1 \end{cases}$$

Then use $P\left(\frac{1-z}{2}<X \right)=1-P\left(X<\frac{1-z}{2} \right)$. And you have to adjust the limits: $x=0 \Rightarrow z=1, x=1\Rightarrow z=-1$

Therefore the cdf of $Z$ is

$$F_Z(z)=\begin{cases}0, \text{if} \ z<-1 \\ 1-\frac{1-z}{2}, \text{if} \ -1 \leq z<1 \\ 1, \text{if} \ z\geq 1 \end{cases}$$

Is Z uniformly distributed on $(-1,1)$ ?